# As a jungle how do i pick/play against a tank comp?

Tags: league-of-legends

Thanks to the buffs made in both crowd control as well as health/tank items being easier to build. There have been a lot of people building tank comps like "Cho'gath mid, Sion jungle, Maokia top , leona support, with a long range adc or high poke like corki or jinx". i have had a very hard time time playing against comps like this. My main champions at the moment have been Volibear, Rek'Sai, Nautilus and Master Yi.

1. What champions are best against these comps?
2. How should I play against them as well?

Currently I build according to what the enemy's biggest threat is and/or on how far ahead I am compared to that threat. Quick example is on Rek'Sai I rush hydra if they have a fed ap laner then slowly build visage but I change that to something more economical if i am behind.

3. If I should change how I itemize how should i change it

One last thing I didn't add early on which had been happening a lot also due to the tank meta that is upon us. I'm not going to add anymore to this but it is something that I think needs some attention as well.

Another not so completely jungle but game related is this. I've had a lot of games where again dealing with a tank comp and there is a team fight. For some very very odd reason my team does not focus the tank or front line they always try to get to the back line even though their champs are not tanky and are completely shut down by the enemy team's cc. quick example here would be a kata diving a carry with a leona or cho'gath maokia protecting him.

4. Lastly how do you team fight against these compositions, and how should you also get your team to fight them or help you when using the strategy you use in these situations?

Comment: If the enemy team is extremely tank-based, then your itemization should be more towards armour shredding if you go offensive - LW, Black Cleaver, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what type of jungler you prefer to be.

**Assassin**

Glasscannon Shaco, non Bruiser Rengar, Kha'Zix etc, your job is to kill the enemy Carries. Your team shouldn't have more than 1 assassin against a tank composition (because too many assassins means that the enemy team can just walk over to you because you lack a front line ), so you take out the enemy carry (and go back before everything collapses on you). Taking out the carry means that they won't have anyone capable of destroying YOUR frontline so your team can easily follow up. Master Yi falls in this, mid game.

**Bruiser**

Rek'sai, Volibear, Rengar, Kha'Zix (provided they actually build some defense), your job is part assassin part tank. Should you engage? Yes. Should you stay and do damage? Maybe. Should you try to kill the backline? Not really. Your job is to disrupt. You go in, preferably into the carries to force the enemy frontline to actually come down on you (and this is why you must have defense), and ***keep them there*** so your own team can follow up on your engage. Once that's done, you should either peel for your carry (since he'll be most likely near the enemy tanks/bruisers/assassins) or try to disrupt the ADC so they won't attack your own frontline. If you're getting too low, back to your own backline and just peel if you can, else, go back, try to heal (If fighting near a jungle camp, just do the camp to regain some HP), and go back in to mop up.

**Tank**

Sejuani, Amumu, Nautilus. You're going to fight as equals. You are a tank, they have a lot of tanks. What you want is to outplay the enemy tanks. If you have a good way to engage in your team, you should be trying to bait the enemy team into a position where your team can engage well (just walking up to them may do the trick). If not, and you're the one who should engage, you're screwed. If your team doesn't have any more tanks, you either have to engage and tank 5 because your team can't afford to tank, or you engage and the enemy team's frontline goes into your own team. But there's nothing you can do, except creating picks if that's the case. If you know you can't teamfight, try to catch the enemy alone, and then teamfight, or just stall the enemy team while someone splitpushes.

**Melee ADC**

Tryndamere, Master Yi. Your job is simple. Get items. Mid game, play like an assassin, try to take kills, else just wait for an engage and then go in and back out before you're in risk. Late game, you're an attack damage carry. If your team can hold their ground without fighting, splitpush. Get turrets and then fight (the enemy will usually be sending someone to you, so if you join your team when the enemy splits, you have an easy fight). If not, it's alright. You're a monster. Wait for an engage from either team (preferably yours). Jump right into the enemy carries, you'll probabbly 1-3 shot them. Depending on your health, proceed to the bruisers/assassins and then the tanks.

This means that fighting a tank team is dependant on you having the capability to nullify their damage output (shutting down their carries) or avoiding the fight completly and search for alternative ways to win the game.

Good picks against tank teams are not really that viable in the jungle. The best thing to kill a tank is an ADC, but ADCs struggle in the jungle. Something that does help a lot is percentage damage, a Liandrai's Torment (Magic) or a Blade of the Ruined King (Phisical) are good against health stacking tanks, but then again, it does depend on your role. However, there are junglers who have % damage in their kit, Sejuani and Amumu are two great examples. Combine them with a Liandrai's and you have something that will help damage the tanks (if your ADC can put them low enough with your help, it's a won fight, unless your own tanks are dead)

Comment: This basically covers most of what you will need - I will just add that a few, but very few, ADC can go jungle, albeit with differing amounts of success. For example, Vayne can go jungle and survive pretty well, and she really shreds tanks with BoTRK.

Comment: I was thinking about singling out Vayne, however, her E is in a high cooldown and her early clear isn't really that good. She'd be behind in levels (and she's squishy aswell). It's a possible pick and it could work, but it wouldn't really be viable because she's extremely easily counterjungled (nor could she keep pressure on lanes and dragon)

Comment: For some reason, I've been seing a lot of Vayne jungles nowadays lol...

Comment: In the event my adc is behind how should i proceed

Comment: It depends. Is your adc just behind or he is just bad?
If he's just behind, FEED him, help him get jungle camps, give him lane exp, do everything so he can get items.

If he's just bad, switch your focus to someone else that can bypass frontlines or just avoid tanks easily (eg; Assassins). It will be harder, but doable. 

No tank (except with Baron) can be good at pushing turrets, which means if you do get their carries, even if you can't win the fight, you won't lose the game

Comment: @Oak: That makes so much sense i feel stupid for even commenting on that. I guess on one part I lose faith in my team to be useful I focus too much on myself instead of trying to help my team which is highly likely the reason that games never go well when I have an adc who is behind. I have never really done anything like that giving my jungle camps to someone who is feeding because my mindset then is this player sucks that gold is wasted on them.

Answer (score 0):

Something to try and counter a team like that would be if you can have your adc play Vayne or Kog'Maw and you play someone with good CC to protect them. Amumu would be a strong suggestion in my opinion since he has pretty good CC and has AOE % health damage.